# Date question re date_popup

Tags: javascript, datetime

In the Date module I'm trying to customize #date_popup; is it possible to completely eliminate the Timepicker field; it currently displays Date + Time fields. I only want the Date field and can't figure out how to remove it in Drupal and/or the Dashboard.

Anyone tried this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

On the "Date attributes to collect", uncheck "hour", "minute" and "second". These options are available on the "DATE FIELD SETTINGS" group of the field configuration screen.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In Configuration > Date API > Date Tools > Date Wizard > Date Field I don't see a "Date attributes to collect" or a place to uncheck "hour" "minute" "second"; I'm using Drupal 7

Comment: Read the answer again, _field_ settings, not date settings.

Comment: You have to go to Structure > Content types > [click on the desired content type] > manage fields > [click on your date field]... and there you are.

Comment: so was able to uncheck "hour" "minute" "second" in the date field under Structure > field settings (thanks!); now on my form i'm simply trying to remove the "Time" field; the Date API auto-displays "Time" when you set "date_popup"; any thoughts on how to remove this in .css or .module so "Time" doesn't display in my frontend form?